# Combining two dictionaries with sub-dictionaries and updating values?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have two dictionaries:

`d1 = {'Cat': {'White': 1}, 'Dog': {'Brown': 4, 'White': 2}}`

`d2 = {'Cat': {'Grey': 6, 'White': 3}, 'Rabbit': {'Brown': 4, 'White': 2}}`

And I want to combine these dictionaries into a single dictionary while updating values for common values in the sub-dictionaries of d1 and d2 for matching keys in d1 and d2.

So if I combine d1 and d2, I would like to get:

```
combined = {'Cat': {'Grey': 6, 'White': 4}, 'Dog': {'Brown': 4, 'White': 2}, 'Rabbit': {'Brown': 4, 'White': 2}}
```

I am new to python so any help is appreciated.

Comment: So to be clear, Grey Cats disappeared because `d1` does not have Grey Cats? (That is, you are taking the union at the first level and then taking the intersection at the second level.)

Comment: Sorry that was a mistake. I have edited it to include grey cats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess there is also a module for that purpose (e.g. collections module -> counter) but this is one solution:

```
def combine_dicts(d1, d2):
    combined = {}
    for key in d1:
        combined[key] = {}
        for key2 in d1[key]:
            combined[key][key2] = d1[key][key2]
    for key in d2:
        if key in combined:
            for key2 in d2[key]:
                if key2 in combined[key]:
                    combined[key][key2] += d2[key][key2]
                else:
                    combined[key][key2] = d2[key][key2]
        else:
            combined[key] = {}
            for key2 in d2[key]:
                combined[key][key2] = d2[key][key2]
    return combined

d1 = {'Cat': {'White': 1}, 'Dog': {'Brown': 4, 'White': 2}}
d2 = {'Cat': {'Grey': 6, 'White': 3}, 'Rabbit': {'Brown': 4, 'White': 2}}

print(combine_dicts(d1, d2))
```

```
Output: {'Cat': {'White': 4, 'Grey': 6}, 'Dog': {'Brown': 4, 'White': 2}, 'Rabbit': {'Brown': 4, 'White': 2}}
```